# referring to self from within self in python

Tags: python, parsing, interpreter, interactive, self

I am not even sure whether the title of my question is correct, but I will fire away anyway. But I would like to apologise, if it turns out that the title is not entirely correct. Also, I have to admit that I am not a guru, as far as python is concerned, so if my question is stupid, just have a good laugh!

I have defined a python class that uses the code.interpreter module. (Basically, I am trying to write a primitive console.) I can pass strings to the interpreter, and everything works fine. However, I would like to do the string parsing outside of this class, so what I have tried to do is to pass the string that I read from the command line to my parser function, which in turn, returns a string. (It expands the original string into a valid python statement.) I take this string, and pass it to the interpreter. This still works fine. However, when the returned string contains a reference to a function defined in my original class, it breaks, and python complains that self.whatever is not defined. Perhaps, the following snippet would make things a bit clearer

```
class myclass():
    ...
    parsed_line = parser.parse_line('line to parse')
    code.InteractiveInterpreter.runsource( parsed_line )

    def self.do_something( self ):
        print 'I have done something'


    pass
```

and my external function

```
def parse_line( line ):
    if 'line' = 'line to parse'
        return 'self.do_something()'
```

Well, it will break. If I modify my parser as

```
def parse_line( line ):
    return 'print 12'
```

it works all right, and happily prints 12. Actually, the reference to self.do_something is not really important. Even if I tried to do a simply assignment to, say, self.a, it would still break.

My question is, how can one overcome the problem described above? I really have to refer to self.whatever, because the function do_something operates on one of the class members in myclass.

Thanks,

Zoltán

Comment: I know quite a few people who start crying over python code not in [Pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @user912866: Why `class myclass():`? That creates an old style class, like it would if you'd write `class myclass:`. If you want a new style class, write `class myclass(object):`. And yes, chances are you want a new style class.

Comment: And is the improper style what makes the code not run? ;) Thanks for calling my attention to it, next time I will make sure that it is done correctly! Zoltán

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this part:

```
def self.do_something( self ):
    print 'I have done something'
```

to just:

```
def do_something( self ):
    print 'I have done something'
```

When you call a method, you use self.some_method().  When you define it, you just define it with the parameter `self`, which will be implicitly passed in.

**EDIT**:

You also need to give your Interactive Interpreter a little help to tell it what context it should run in, by passing in the locals():

change this:

```
code.InteractiveInterpreter.runsource( parsed_line )
```

to something like this:

```
interpreter = code.InteractiveInterpreter(locals())
interpreter.runsource( parsed_line )
```

Comment: Hi Gerrat, it seems that adding the locals fixed the problem. Thanks! Also, do_something was defined without the self., this typo occurred only when I copied my code to stackoverflow. Zoltán

Answer (score 2):

`self` is not magic in Python like in some other languages; it's merely conventionally used as the first parameter for instance method calls, since the instance is passed to the method as this parameter. It has no meaning within a class declaration, only within the body of the instance method.

Answer (score 0):

If your class C is fixed, you can call the method as

```
Myclass.do_something(self)
```

But this is not good style. What is the reason to call a function outside ???

You could define

```
def parse_something(obj, line):
    obj.do_something()
```

Could you elaborate what you want to do ? I think there is a better, more
object oriented way to do it.

Comment: Your last method works, but that is not I want to do. I would like to keep parsing and the action resulting from parsing in separate places. And basically, this is why I would like to handle parsing in a separate function. In my first class, a keypress with 'Return' simply takes the line, passes it to the parser, and the parser produces the command to be executed. In this way, the first class is kept simple and clean, and the parser does not tamper with objects in myclass.

Comment: So, if parsing and the resulting action are separate parts, why do you need this kind of "cross access" from one class to the other  ??? so they are not separated at all. This is a strong code smell..... 

You should at least write some kind of manager which holds instances to you both classes and orchestrates their work.

Comment: They are separated, and as I pointed out in my reply to Gerrat, the problem was that the code generated by the parser was not executed in the proper context. Once I added locals() to the interpreter, the code worked all right. Thanks for the comments!